# How to hide an item on a report?

Tags: report, openerp-7, accounting

I did some changes one of the method on accounting report in OpenERP. My problem now is how can i make some item invisible or delete? In particular, I want to hide the "Liability" and its balance on the report.

I tried something like this on get_lines method:

```
for report in lines:
    if report["name"].lower().replace(" ","") == 'liability':
         del report["name"]
         del report["balance"]
```

but when i tried to generate Balance sheet report. It says:

```
(<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>,KeyError('name',), <traceback object at 0x7f6c4c2903f8>)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error that raises when you try to access **object key** that **doesn't exist**. In your case "name".

**Error** you have is "logical" error, simply go into debug and see what you get in report variable inside loop.

Moreover, to change report content (and by report I think you mean **pdf output** right?) you need to override **.rml** file. I think you are changing report parser here, which is also ok if you know what you are doing.

Here you can find **RML documentation**: http://www.reportlab.com/docs/rml2pdf-userguide.pdf

So, to sum: to change report output content override or replace parser, to change structure, hide/add fields override existing report (**.rml** file) or create entirely new report.

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When i tried to log report in my for loop it displays a dictionary. I also checked the .rml but i can not understand what the code is all about.

Comment: I added RML documentation link in answer. As for parser (python code) you will have to adjust it to work, without further code I won't be able to help. Up-vote if you find answer useful :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the good (or perhaps the weirdest) solution to the problem but after reading about .rml and i can't still comprehend this is what i did. Instead of trying to delete **report["name"]** and **report["balance"]** i just set it's value into a white space. This time it's no longer shown on the report.